# Как совместить тип форматирования snprintf и scanf?

Tags: c

Как можно совместить snprintf(format,"%%%zus", count); с таким типом форматирования: fscanf(stdin, "%*[^\"]%*c%[^\"]", name) ? (считывать от кавычек до кавычек)

Comment: Что значит _совместить_?

Comment: @EOF, чтобы было приблизительно так: snprintf(format,"%*[^\"]%*c%[^\"]", count); (но это не работает)

Comment: А где должно появиться значение `count` в строке?

Comment: @EOF, count - кол-во считываемых символов

Comment: Т.е. Вам нужно прочитать `count` символов, которые находятся между кавычками?

Comment: @EOF, да. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Если у вас GNU, посмотрите на `optional assignment-allocation character 'm'` в форматах [scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для чтения всего, что находится между кавычек, нужно вызвать `scanf` так:

```
char str[64];
scanf("%*[^\"]\"%[^\"]%*[^\n]", str);
```

Давайте разберём этот пример.
Часть `%*[^\"]` заставляет `scanf` пропустить всё до первого символа `"`. Но оставляет его в очереди. Дальше `\"` заставит функцию пропустить оставшийся символ `"`. Потом, с помощью `%[^\"]` функция читает всё, до следующего символа `"` и сохраняет это в `str`. Ну и наспоследок, `%*[^\n]` пропустит всё, что осталось. **ВАЖНО! Оставит символ `\n` во входной очереди**.
Например, при вводе строки `I am a "test string" for this programm.`
в `str` будет записоно `test string`.
Для указания необходимого количества символов для чтения будем использовать `snprintf`. Что бы создать необходимый формат, нужно вызвать её так:

```
char fmt[32];
snprintf(fmt, sizeof fmt, "%%*[^\"]\"%%%d[^\"]%%*[^\n]", count);
```

где `count`- это необходимое количество символов для чтения. После этого, в `fmt` будет находиться строка, которую можно передать `scanf`. Вызов будет таким:

```
scanf(fmt, str);
```

Comment: Может быть формат, считывающий кавычки (а может только закрывающую кавычку) был бы лучше? (он позволит просто контролировать, все ли смволы внутри кавычек поместились в переменную). / Вообще же говоря (это уже скорее к @AnnaErion), если вы решаете достаточно общую задачу ввода текста, то мучения с такими форматами scanf это бесплодное занятие (хотя бы из-за того, что вам нужно как-то представлять кавычки **внутри** закавыченного текста, и такую грамматику вы scanf-ом не разберете). Подумайте сразу над написанием нормального парсера (традиционно из входного потока такие программы читают байты)

Comment: Кстати, такой формат не сработает, если кавычка является первым символом строки.

Comment: @eanmos Да, не предусмотрел. Попробую позже исправить. Если есть идеи - поделитесь)

Comment: @EOF, да просто проверить первый символ, и, если это кавычка, то убрать эту часть − %*[^\"] − из формата.